# Changing a list output after a certain number of variables

Tags: python, django, list, django-templates

I have a list:

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

in my template, I want to output this as follows:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to make it more generic, you can also use the built in [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) tag

```
{% for value in c %}

    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:cut_off %}
        <table>
            <tr>
    {% endif %}

    <td>{{value}}</td>

    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:cut_off %}
            </tr>
        </table>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

where `c` is the list and `cut_off` is the slicing number (e.g. 4 in your question). These variables are supposed to be sent the to the template in your view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) template filter:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    {% for value in c|slice:":4" %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    {% for value in c|slice:"4:" %}
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
```

Assuming `c` is passed in the template context.

`slice` basically follows usual python [slicing syntax](http://www.diveintopython3.net/native-datatypes.html#slicinglists):

```
>>> c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> c[:4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c[4:]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```